# Rewrite apply function to use recursion instead

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

Probably the hardest part of learning lisp has been to think in the "lisp way" which is elegant and impressive, but not always easy. I know that recursion is used to solve a lot of problems, and I am working through a book that instead uses `apply` to solve a lot of problems, which I understand is not as lispy, and also not as portable.

An experienced lisper should be able to help with this logic without knowing specifically what `describe-path`, `location`, and `edges` refer to. Here is an example in a book I am working through:

```
(defun describe-paths (location edges)
  (apply (function append) (mapcar #'describe-path
               (cdr (assoc location edges)))))
```

I have successfully rewritten this to avoid `apply` and use recursion instead. It seems to be working:

```
(defun describe-paths-recursive (location edges)
  (labels ((processx-edge (edge)
         (if (null edge)
         nil
         (append (describe-path (first edge))
             (processx-edge (rest edge))))))
    (processx-edge (cdr (assoc location edges)))))
```

I would like some more seasoned pairs of eyes on this to advise if there is a more elegant way to translate the `apply` to recursion, or if I have done something unwise. This code seems decent, but would there been something even more "lispy" ?

Comment: why do you think using apply is a bad style? I saw several similar opinions, but didn't get any arguments for that.

Comment: Using `apply` isn't non-Lispy, but using `(apply function ...)` can be an issue if you don't know how big the list can be.

Comment: Cross posted on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/q/20188008/1281433.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Lisp is a multiparadigm language.

[`apply`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm) is just as lispy as recursion, and, in a way, much more so (think in HOFs)!

## Style

1. Please fix indentation.
2. Please write `#'foo` instead of `(function foo)`.

## Implementations

The first (HOF) version can be much more efficiently rewritten in using [`mapcan`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) (provided `defscribe-path` returns fresh lists):

```
(defun describe-paths (location edges)
  (mapcan #'describe-path
          (cdr (assoc location edges)))))
```

The second (recursive) version can be made tail recursive using an accumulator. This would help some compilers produce better code.

```
(defun describe-paths-recursive (location edges)
  (labels ((processx-edge (edge acc)
             (if (null edge)
                 acc
                 (processx-edge (rest edge) 
                                (revappend acc (describe-path (first edge)))))))
    (nreverse (processx-edge (cdr (assoc location edges))))))
```

Note the use of [`revappend`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_revapp.htm)/[`nreverse`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_revers.htm) instead of `append` to avoid quadraticity.

Comment: is the accumulator a requirement for tail recursion optimization, or just a hint that could potentially be ignored?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid an accumulator if you write a tail recursive version, but you can try (or maybe I did not understand your question)